# HTTPS no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Comprei um certificado e passei minha url de http para https no wordpress. Usei as seguintes maneiras:

> Vá até “Configurações” de seu WordPress, em “Geral” altere o “Endereço
>   do WordPress (URL)” e “Endereço do site (URL)” para
>   “https://www.seudominio.com”, caso não use o WWW coloque apenas
>   “https://seudominio.com”, após salvar você poderá perder o acesso
>   temporariamente ao seu WordPress, não faça nada, apenas continue.

**Depois no `wp-config.php`:**

```
define('FORCE_SSL_CONTENT', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

**E por fim no arquivo `htaccess`:**

```
# BEGIN SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
# END SSL
```

Muitas páginas são redirecionadas, de http para https, mas uma das que não redireciona, é a página de erro 404 e ás vezes ocorrem erros do usuário estar logado, e quando atualizo a página ele não esta mais, daí atualiza de novo ele volta a estar logado.

Alguém conhece algum jeito de redirecionar todos, sem ter problemas como os que estão acontecendo em meu site?

Comment: Use o plugin Really Simple SSL: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ Já testei vários e este foi o que teve melhor resultado e foi o mais fácil de utilizar.

Comment: Atualmente não está dando mais erros, mas valeu pela dica... ATT

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar adicionar no `.htaccess`:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.seudominio.com/$1 [NC,R,L]`